# How to create infinite questions based app in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

So I am building an app where I need to ask user unknown amount of questions, it can be 5 or it can be 50, it wouldn't make sense to make 50 screens. I have 4 types of questions and that would be 4 components. And I want to keep all 5-... question on single screen, but they need to change when I press "NEXT". Is that good aproach at all, and how to do that? Just explanation you don't have to bother with writing all the code. And if there is any other aproach to that?

If you need any more info please comment.

Thank you!

Comment: try to watch this https://www.sitepoint.com/simple-javascript-quiz/ maybe it will help you

Comment: in the lower part of the page there is a complete example

Comment: Thank you for the link I will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a conditional render. Depending on your state value, return a different component to render and every time you press next update your state. This way you wont need to change screens.

```
render () {
 swtich(this.state.questionType) {
    case 1: return <Quest01 />
    case 2: return <Quest02 />
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

Comment: If state : 1, and it shows question 1 lets say, when state: 2, will it remove question 1 and show question 2?

Comment: I mean this looks perfect